# Restrict Community users' access to files

Tags: community, sharing, files

We have an object, call it `MainObject__c` that is a master object. There are several other objects with a Master-Detail relationship to it. This is a given and cannot be changed.

One of those objects, `Request__c`, is available for editing to a small subset of Community users. They have their own Profile and Permission Set.
Among the things they are allowed to edit are files. They can upload and delete files on the `Request__c` object.

Each user is only allowed to access one or more specific `Request__c` records. We control this on the frontend via our Angular app, and in the backend via trigger checks on records.
This works well.

What doesn't work so well is the fact that a user can view files uploaded to `Request__c` records to which they have no access. For example:
Alice will upload a file to a `Request__c` record to which she has access.
Alice can view this file, and download it via a link like

```
https://instance.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/069XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Alice can email that link to Bob, who does **not** have access to Alice's `Request__c` record, and yet he can download the file she uploaded.

This is a big no-no and we would like to prevent it.
Ideally I'd like to find a way to allow per record sharing access on `Request__c` object, but I fear that may not be possible due to its Master-Detail relationship and being controlled by parent.

Another possible solution would be to block the download in Apex from an unauthorized user. But I have no idea how (or even if) that can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we eventually implemented involved changing the schema of our org.
We created a new object `SecureRequest__c` instead of `Request__c`.
`SecureRequest__c` has a Lookup to `MainObject__c` instead of Master-Detail.
All other fields are identical (yes, API Name as well), and so we were able to (mostly) continue using existing code with just a few modifications.

This allowed us to define new sharing settings and rules for `SecureRequest__c`, and thus prevent unwanted file access.